# JavaScript / jQuery not on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i create an action for an element which will change when the user is not over it. `mouseover` and `mouseleave` can't be applied in this situation because the element is activated on page load and the mouse location can be outside the element.

Here is the condition:

```
if mouse is not over element:
   close element
else:
   do nothing
```

So what i want to know is how can i check with jQuery/JavaScript if the current mouse position is not on the specific element.

Thanks!!

Comment: So why not initialize it hidden and use `mouseover()` to show it?

Comment: It's a dropdown which stays dropped when the page refreshes. During the refresh time if the user moves the mouse out of the dropdown box it won't close.

Comment: Page refresh? Are you talking about a full page reload? Why would you be worried about what something looks like when the page is reloaded? Perhaps I'm missing some vital clues ;-)

Comment: Well it's not really my idea, i'm just implementing it.. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind the event handler to the body and check for the requested target:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("body").on('mouseover',function(event) {
        if($(event.target).attr('id') === 'yourid' ) {
            console.log('do close this element');
        } else {
            console.log('do nothing');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a global boolean to keep track of whether the mouse is currently hovering over the element or not. Then, you can periodically check that boolean using `setInterval` (with some reasonable time interval) which will decide whether the element should be hidden or not.

```
var mouseIsOver = false;

$('#elementId').hover(
  function () {
    mouseIsOver = true;
  }, 
  function () {
    mouseIsOver = false;
  }
);

setInterval(function() {
  if (mouseIsOver == false) {
    $('#elementId').fadeOut();
  }
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a brilliant jQuery plugin for just this. It's called jQuery outside events.

Check the homepage here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/docs/files/jquery-ba-outside-events-js.html

The usage is super-simple and straight forward. I'd recommend this with great experience earlier.